# iOS 8 VPN connect from code, if i have no cert

Tags: ios, objective-c, vpn

The VPN connect is not Working from code.
Why is not connected to the server?
The code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // init VPN manager
    self.vpnManager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];

    // load config from perference
    [vpnManager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Load config failed [%@]", error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }

        if (vpnManager.protocol) {
            // config exists
        }

        // config IPSec protocol
        NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
        p.username = @"username";
        p.serverAddress = @"serveraddress";

        // get password persistent reference from keychain
        NSString *password = @"thepassword";
        NSData *paswordData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        p.passwordReference = paswordData;

        // PSK
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
        NSString *secret = @"123654987";
        NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        p.sharedSecretReference = secretData;


        p.useExtendedAuthentication = NO;
        p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;

        vpnManager.protocol = p;
        vpnManager.localizedDescription = @"vpnusers@dyndns.org";

        [vpnManager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Save config failed [%@]", error.localizedDescription);
        }];

    }];

   }

static NSString * const serviceName = @"com.progserv.vpn_config";

-(NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatching:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSData *encodedIdentifier = [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword;
    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric] = encodedIdentifier;
    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] = encodedIdentifier;
    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecAttrService] = serviceName;

    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne;
    searchDictionary[(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef] = @YES;

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &result);

    return (__bridge_transfer NSData *)result;
}


- (IBAction)CreateVPN:(id)sender {
    NSError *startError;
    [vpnManager.connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];


    if (startError) {
        NSLog(@"Start VPN failed: [%@]", startError.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your completion handler for `loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler` even get called? Mine is never called in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If `loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler` is never called, you probably haven't yet created an app-specific provisioning profile w/ VPN services enabled in Apple's developer portal... I'm sure you've seen this article, but the provisioning profile piece is very important: http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/